# Excel to MySQL replace all '-' with none or null in three hundred columns in Kettle/pdi?

Tags: excel, kettle, pdi

I have three hundred columns from excel to MySQL, there are so many values with `-`, how to insert data to MySQL with none or null instead of `-`, is there any easy way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

You have different methods, the first that comes to my mind is the *Replace in string* step. Specify `-` as the character to search and mark *Set empty string?* as Y.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have three hundred columns, maybe I have to type all columns in string step?

Comment: At present, I use JavaScript to replace them, `if(test_a='-')
 test_a = null

if(test_b ='-')
    test_b = null`, but it's troublesome.

Comment: Upon re-reading your question, the *Replace in string* step is not what you need, because it will always change the "-" character whenever it appears in the string, not only when it matchs exactly that value. The *Null if* step is more accurate. If you want to avoid writing all the columns in the step (you can use the Get fields, but anyway you'll have to write the value to convert to null), you can use metadata injection, that step allows it.